# syntax error, unexpected keyword_else

Tags: ruby

Who can tell me how to solve the error as title?
How to use a nested if-else sentence?
Thank U.

```
b = Array.new(n,0)
c = Array.new(n) {Array.new(n,0)}
n.times do |i|
    a[i], b[i] = gets.split(" ").map(&:to_i)
end

n.times do |i|
    w.times do |j|
        i=i+1
        j=j+1
        if a[i-1] > j || i > k then
            c[i][j] = c[i-1][j]
        else
            if c[i-1][j] < c[i-1][j-a[i-1]]+b[i-1] then
                c[i][j] = c[i-1][j-a[i-1]]+b[i-1]
                k--
            else
                c[i][j] = c[i-1][j]
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as the increment/decrement operator in Ruby.

Replace `k--` with `k -= 1`.

You could also use compound operators for these:

```
i += 1 # previously i=i+1
j += 1 # previously j=j+1
```